# Como realizar una resta antes de realizar un cambio de checkbox, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen dia, tengo una tabla que contiene varios checkbox, al hacer click en un checkbox ejecuta la siguiente funcion:

```
$$('#prestamos_creditos').on('click', '.prestamo', function(){


    $('input.prestamo').not(this).prop('checked', false); //En esta ultima se produce el cambio de checkbox, es decir selecciona otro checkbox y desmarca el checkbox que estaba selecciado, con el fin de que solo 1 checkbox este seleccionado,

   if ($(this).is(':checked')){
  //Aca obtengo y realizo procedimientos si esta chequeado.
 }
        else{
//Aca ejecut otros procedimientos al desmarcar el checkbox.
}
    });
```

Antes de que se realice el cambio de checkbox `$('input.prestamo').not(this).prop('checked', false);` debo realizar la siguiente suma y resta

```
saldo_pendiente_cancelar += montoPrestamo;
monto_favor -= montoPrestamo;
$('.saldo_pendiente').text(moneda(saldo_pendiente_cancelar));
```

Comment: ¿De cuántos checkbox estamos hablando?  ¿Por qué no usas mejor un radio button, que te evita más de uno seleccionado a la vez y escuchas el `on change` de esos radio, haciendo allí la operación?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función que haga dicha operación y la invoques cada vez que quieres y en el lugar de tu código que creas que sea necesario por ejemplo:

Función donde se hace la operación:

```
const sumaResta = () => {
  ... //Aquí va el resto del código donde obtienes los valores de montoPrestamo
      //o si lo pasas por parametro a la función 
  saldo_pendiente_cancelar += montoPrestamo;
  monto_favor -= montoPrestamo;
  $('.saldo_pendiente').text(moneda(saldo_pendiente_cancelar)
}
```

Invocando dicha función en el evento click:

```
    $$('#prestamos_creditos').on('click', '.prestamo', function(){

      sumaResta();//Aquí llamas a la función    

      $('input.prestamo').not(this).prop('checked', false); //En esta ultima se produce el cambio de checkbox, es decir selecciona otro checkbox y desmarca el checkbox que estaba selecciado, con el fin de que solo 1 checkbox este seleccionado,

      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
      //Aca obtengo y realizo procedimientos si esta chequeado.
      }
      else{
      //Aca ejecut otros procedimientos al desmarcar el checkbox.
      }

    });
```

Espero que esto te pueda guiar.

Comment: Fijate David, que no realiza bien el procedimiento matematico.

Comment: dices que tienes error es en la suma y la resta? ese es el problema?